# Chunked file uploads in Softlayer PHP Client

Tags: php, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to upload large files to Softlayer Object Storage. How can I do this using PHP Client for Object Storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a php example to upload files using [SoftLayer Object Storage PHP Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-php):

```
<?php
require_once ('lib/ObjectStorage/Util.php');

class ObjectStorageSL{

    var $objectStorage;
    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $options) {

        $this -> objectStorage = new ObjectStorage($host, $username, $password, $options);

    }

    /**
     * This method shows token and url from an object storage
     * @var $objectStorage - Object Storage connection
     */
    function displayTokenUrl() {
        print("Token: " . $this -> objectStorage -> getAuthenticationData() -> authToken . "\n");
        print("Url: " . $this -> objectStorage -> getAuthenticationData() -> objectStorageUrl);
    }

    /**
     * This method uploads a file located in your local machine
     * @var $objectStorage - Object Storage connection
     * @var $containerName - The container's name where you want to upload the object
     * @var $objectName - The object's name that you wish to assign for the file uploaded
     * @var $path - The path where the file is located
     */
    function uploadFile($containerName, $objectName, $path) {
        try {
            $result = $this -> objectStorage -> with($containerName . "/" . $objectName) -> setLocalFile($path) -> create();
            print("\n".$result -> getUrl());
            print("\nThe file has been uploaded");
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo "\nError: " . $e -> getMessage();
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Declare Object Storage parameters
 */
$host = 'https://mil01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0/';
// Declare your username and password for Object Storage connection
$username = 'set me';
$password = 'set me';
$options = array('adapter' => ObjectStorage_Http_Client::SOCKET, 'timeout' => 10);

/**
 * Create Object Storage Connection
 */
$objectStorage = new ObjectStorageSL($host, $username, $password, $options);

/**
 * Display Token and Url
 */
$objectStorage -> displayTokenUrl();
$path = "C:\Project\task.xml";
$objectStorage -> uploadFile("rcvTest", "task1.xml", $path);
```

I didn't test it with files bigger than 10 MB, but it should work, let me know if you have troubles or any question

Comment: I'm using this approach right now and this is not 100% that i need.

E.g. I have file with size of 50mb. Can I split him in 5 parts and upload them one by one and gather together them into Softlayer server? (first request will create file, other requests will append data to the file or something like this)

Comment: Unfortunately for large files, I didn't see any method in the client to split it.

Anyway, take a look this information, probably it will help you: 
http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/api/large_objects.html